# How to create a docker-compose to Sybase

Tags: docker, docker-compose, sybase

Im trying to create a docker-compose with db2, sql-server and sybase but I have a problem. When I run

```txt
docker-compose up
```

This get this error:

```txt
Creating sybase ... error
Creating db2 ... 
Creating mssql ... done
ERROR: for sybase  Cannot create container for service sybase: No command specified
```

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```txt
version: '3'
services:
  db2:
    container_name: db2
    privileged: true
    image: "ibmcom/db2express-c:latest"
    environment:
      LICENSE: accept
      DB2INST1_PASSWORD: "abcd.1234"
    ports:
    - "50000:50000"
  mssql:
    container_name: mssql
    image: "microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest"
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: "abcd.1234"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
    ports:
    - "1433:1433"
  sybase:
    container_name: sybase
    image: "ifnazar/sybase_15_7:latest"
    ports:
        - "5000:5000"
    hostname: dksybase hostname: dksybase
```

The configuration of db2 and sql-server it's ok. The only problem is Sybase! The only information of sybase where I found in forums is Dockerfile, but by now, I dont need create a new image. I only need a docker-compose file with their configuration.

I hope you can help me! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By inspecting [ifnazar/sybase_15_7](https://hub.docker.com/r/ifnazar/sybase_15_7/) image documentation I can tell that it requires a command as you can see by the error message. Simply add one to the docker-compose file:

```
sybase:
  (...)
  command: ["bash", "/sybase/start"]
```